# How can I get the tweet's replies/comments in Twitter SDK

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric

I have a requirement to get all the replies of a particular tweet and the persons who made my post as favorite.

In 1.1, I can able to get the favorite_count, but no API/Method to get the list of users ?

I used Fabric Android SDK as well as REST API's

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is as follows:

To find a replies to `Tweet myTweet` I used the Search API. I query for all Tweets directed at the Tweet's author posted after the Tweet. The code looks like the following.

```
Twitter
    .getApiClient()
    .getSearchService()
    .tweets("to:" + myTweet.user.screenName, null, null, null, null, null, null, myTweet.id, null, null)
    .enqueue(new Callback<Search>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Search> result) {
            for(Tweet tweet : result.data.tweets){
                if(tweet.inReplyToStatusId == myTweet.id){
                    // Do something with the reply //
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It isn't perfect, but since there is no official supported way to get replies, this works enough.